# Shell inside docker not printing env var values

Tags: bash, docker, shell

I'm running an inline shell script on docker using

```
InlineShell=$(cat <<<-EOF
echo "printing values"
echo "$SAMPLE_VAL"
echo "end of printing values"
echo "printing env vars"
env
EOF
)
docker run -e SAMPLE_VAL="Sample Value" <image> /bin/bash -c $InlineShell
```

After executing I'm able to see the env variable set but the value is not printed/echoed by the inline shell script.

```
printing values
end of printing values
printing env vars
SAMPLE_VAL=Sample Value
```

Above is the output I get along with some other env vars printed. Tried both $SAMPLE_VAL and ${SAMPLE_VAL} still the same result.

Comment: You're expanding the values outside, before storing the content in `InlineShell`. Use `cat <<'EOF'`, with quotes around the sigil on the starting side, to avoid that.

Comment: Also, `bash -c "$InlineShell"` needs the quotes if your outer shell is POSIXy (which is to say, not zsh; and since bash is the only shell your question mentions, I have to assume it's the one you're running). Leaving them out breaks things -- setting `IFS=` avoids _some_ failure cases from missing quotes, but not all of them.